# How to handle single quotes in PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, prepared-statement

I want to use a *prepared statement* like this:

```
acl = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO acls_t(user,topic,rw) values((SELECT id from users_t where username=?),'?/#',1);");
mqtt_acl.setString(1, name);
mqtt_acl.setString(2, uuid);
```

My database is MariaDB and does not accept this.
It returns the following error:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 2 (values was '3aa4ea54-3105-47a3-9bfb-c17c4348d84a')
> Query - conn:56(M)  - "INSERT INTO acls_t(user,topic,rw) values((SELECT id from users_t where username=?),'?/#',1);"
> ```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Are you meaning for the second parameter to be a concatenation of the passed in parameter and '/#'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
acl = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO acls_t(user,topic,rw) values((SELECT id from users_t where username=?),?,1);");
mqtt_acl.setString(1, name);
mqtt_acl.setString(2, uuid + "/#");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sql statement could be simplified to this:

```
INSERT INTO acls_t(user,topic,rw) SELECT id, CONCAT(?, '/#'), 1 FROM users_t WHERE username = ?;
```

without the use of `VALUES` for which you must nest the `SELECT` statement.
So change your code to:

```
acl = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO acls_t(user,topic,rw) SELECT id, CONCAT(?, '/#'), 1 FROM users_t WHERE username = ?;");
mqtt_acl.setString(1, uuid);
mqtt_acl.setString(2, name);
```

With this code if there is no user in the table `users_t` with `username` equal to the value of the variable `name` then no  row will be inserted, but your code will try to insert a row to the table `acls_t` and set the column `user` with `null`.